# invalid initialization of reference of type

Tags: c++

There is a function `isInstruction()` in my code (not mine) which is used for setting and getting a member with no problem. Now I added my own function for similar purpose `state()`. Like this:

```
struct foo {
  bool & isInstruction() {
    return isInst;    // no problem
  }
  int & state() {
    return state;   //ERROR
  } 
private:
  bool isInst;
  int state;  
};
```

I have no problem with the first function. But for the second one, I get

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type 
‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’
```

Then question is what is the difference between these two functions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that the two entities (the member variable and the member function) are sharing the same name, `state`, which is what's causing the problem.

Try renaming one of them.

Comment: I was 1ms away from hitting post.